# Change tikz rectangle location based on the page numbering

Tags: templates, cv

I am trying to modify the [TwentySecondsCV](https://github.com/spagnuolocarmine/TwentySecondsCurriculumVitae-LaTex) but I got a very confusing problem. I cannot find any solution to continue the CV on the next side in that way that the colored box moves to the right side of the page.

Have you got any suggestions how one could do that?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: *This template has been designed to create a "one-page" résumé is therefore not suitable to create curriculum of more than one-page.

    Please do not try to create curriculum more than one-page.*

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should go to the line 149 in `twentysecondcv.cls` and change

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node [rectangle, fill=asidecolor, anchor=north, 
     minimum width=9.90cm, minimum height=\paperheight+1cm] (box) 
     at (-5cm,0.5cm){};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

to something like this:

```
\ifodd\value{page}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
      \node [rectangle, fill=asidecolor, anchor=north, 
      minimum width=9.90cm, minimum height=\paperheight+1cm] (box) 
      at (-5cm,0.5cm){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\else
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
      \node [rectangle, fill=asidecolor, anchor=north, 
      minimum width=9.90cm, minimum height=\paperheight+1cm] (box) 
      at (\paperwidth-4.90cm,0.5cm){};
\fi%
```

I do not know for what reason it goes outside of the printing region — as if it will be printed in a typography.